# Concurrency in reading and writing files

Tags: file-io, concurrency

I have a website and part of my website needs to read/write a plain text file on server. most of the time we have between 50 to 100 concurrent online users and their actions on our site result to read/write certain file in which that is a temporary place holder for some other pages.

So I want to know about concurrent read/write conflicts and what's the best practice to avoid that if that happened. How does my server manage these requests?

Comment: best practice to use some database in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of more importance than the webserver is the underlying OS and filesystem.

You can *(in supported circumstances)* obtain an exclusive lock on a file handle in PHP using [flock()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) causing all other attempts at an exclusive lock to block and stack behind it.

Answer (score 1):

An option in *nix systems is creating a temporary file, writing to it, fsync()ing it, and then rename()ing to the target filename. Of course this only works for a single writer, or if you only want the latest writer.